# What usb device is connected to a usb port

Tags: c++, winapi, usb, drivers

I'll try to keep this simple.
I have a hub connected to my PC. This hub has several USB interfaces. I'm listening to `WM_DEVICECHANGE` event and I get the USB interface path. How can I know what port it was connected to? Looking for a non-WMI solution in c++ or c# for a windows environment.

I tried using `IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_NAME` with `USB_NODE_CONNECTION_NAME` (where `USB_NODE_CONNECTION_NAME.NodeName` will hold the path to the device) but this only works if the device connected to the port is a hub as well.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue in C++ is that there is no standard functions for detecting USB ports.

USB Port identification and implementation is a platform specific issue.  For example, Linux handles USB ports quite differently than Windows and many embedded systems don't have USB ports.

So you'll have to look for a 3rd party library or find some OS API to use for your platform.